# Azure service bus alert notifications at queue/topic level

Tags: azure, servicebus

It is possible to configure an alert on azure sb that gets triggered when dlc reaches a certain threshold or a queue reaches it's maximum.
However it seems these alerts are triggered on namespace level meaning the linked action (like email) is not mentioning the exact queue only the namespace name.
This makes it difficult to find out what queue is causing the problem if a namespace contains multiple queues.

So my question: is it possible to get more information about the queue/topic itself in the alert notification (mail) ?
What are best practices to deal with this kind of requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual entities (queue/topic) will have their individual dead letter queue. The dead letter queue space is added to the total space of the entity.
Your monitor alert will have the Dimensions details about the entity as below.

For more details on the alert refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/monitor-service-bus#alerts)

Service Bus Message Metrices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/monitor-service-bus-reference#message-metrics

[image]